# Why I can't set 2 CPU on virtualbox xp?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I set 2 CPU on virtualbox xp and boot successfully.

[image]

But when I use speccy to check.

It says I only have 1 cpu and only 1 core.

[image]

[image]

What happened?

How do I enable the second CPU?

Thank you~

Comment: Did you enable VT-x in BIOS?

Comment: Did you enable I/O APIC for the VM **before** installing Windows?

Comment: Yes,I have enabled VT-x in BIOS. But I do not enable I/O APIC before installing windows. How to fix it? Thank you~

Comment: may be as an old operating system(Win XP) it wouldn't support 2 CPU in hardware

Comment: Here is solution (use devcon utility and execute two commands) - http://superuser.com/a/456617

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 64-bit guest and if you want to use more than 1 CPU in your guest we need to enable I/O APIC prior to installing Windows.

> Enabling the I/O APIC is required  for 64-bit guest operating systems, especially Windows Vista; it is also required if you want to use more than one virtual CPU in a virtual machine.

[Reference: Virtual Box User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor)

This can be done in the *System -> Motherboard* setting in the **VirtualBox Manager**.

[image]

**Note:** These setting has to be made before installing Windows as only then Windows will be installed with the appropriate kernel.

Comment: I use 32-bit XP. And I also have already enabled IO APIC. What can I do next? Thank you~

Comment: @sam: as said, you may need to reinstall XP with these settings.

Comment: I can't reinstall xp because some software problems. Is there any other way to get this function without reinstall?

Comment: I don't know if you can change the Windows kernel without fresh install (may well be you can't). Consider asking this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://aaklink.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/virtual-box-upgrading-windows-xp-vms-to.html) you can simply run the following in a command prompt within the windows guest: `rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction ACPIAPIC_MP_HAL 128 %windir%\inf\hal.inf` and then reboot twice as prompted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the "Enable IO APIC" checkbox in the System settings of your virtual box guest machine.
2. Run the following in a command prompt inside the windows guest:

rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction ACPIAPIC_MP_HAL 128 %windir%\inf\hal.inf